# Error while building Kafka from source code

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I am trying to build Apache Kafka from source code using [MANASVI GUPTA article](https://manasvigupta.github.io/getting-started-with-contributing-to-apache-kafka-part1-build-and-run-kafka-from-source-code/) in a Ubuntu 18.04 (It is a VMware virtual machine). In the last step of article when I pressed run button I am getting following error:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -javaagent:/snap/intellij-idea-community/85/lib/idea_rt.jar=40013:/snap/intellij-idea-community/85/bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/icedtea-sound.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/jaccess.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/java-atk-wrapper.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/jce.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/management-agent.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/resources.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/rt.jar:/home/morteza/project/kafka/core/out/production/classes:/home/morteza/project/kafka/clients/out/production/classes:/home/morteza/project/kafka/clients/out/production/resources:/home/morteza/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.9.7/e6faad47abd3179666e89068485a1b88a195ceb7/jackson-databind-2.9.7.jar:/home/morteza/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/net.sf.jopt-simple/jopt-simple/5.0.4/4fdac2fbe92dfad86aa6e9301736f6b4342a3f5c/jopt-simple-5.0.4.jar:/home/morteza/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.yammer.metrics/metrics-core/2.2.0/f82c035cfa786d3cbec362c38c22a5f5b1bc8724/metrics-core-2.2.0.jar:/home/morteza/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.typesafe.scala-logging/scala-logging_2.11/3.9.0/e0dba06b4a763a0e2208182b264421baedbb0df/scala-logging_2.11-3.9.0.jar:/home/morteza/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.scala-lang/scala-reflect/2.11.12/2bb23c13c527566d9828107ca4108be2a2c06f01/scala-reflect-2.11.12.jar:/home/morteza/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.scala-lang/scala-library/2.11.12/bf5534e6fec3d665bd6419c952a929a8bdd4b591/scala-library-2.11.12.jar:/home/morteza/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.101tec/zkclient/0.10/c54d4b5a5e89af75a80b6d5857400165ce5188d0/zkclient-0.10.jar:/home/morteza/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.zookeeper/zookeeper/3.4.13/31e9937541cef95c4585b547eb2dbd34d3a76f1c/zookeeper-3.4.13.jar:/home/morteza/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.25/da76ca59f6a57ee3102f8f9bd9cee742973efa8a/slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar:/home/morteza/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.lz4/lz4-java/1.5.0/d36fb639f06aaa4f17307625f80e2e32f815672a/lz4-java-1.5.0.jar:/home/morteza/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.xerial.snappy/snappy-java/1.1.7.2/307b286efd119ad2c6d4291128bf110bddc68088/snappy-java-1.1.7.2.jar:/home/morteza/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations/2.9.0/7c10d545325e3a6e72e06381afe469fd40eb701/jackson-annotations-2.9.0.jar:/home/morteza/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/log4j/log4j/1.2.17/5af35056b4d257e4b64b9e8069c0746e8b08629f/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/home/morteza/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core/2.9.7/4b7f0e0dc527fab032e9800ed231080fdc3ac015/jackson-core-2.9.7.jar:/home/morteza/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.yetus/audience-annotations/0.5.0/55762d3191a8d6610ef46d11e8cb70c7667342a3/audience-annotations-0.5.0.jar kafka.Kafka config/server.properties
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
```

Comment: Are you wanting to build it so as to develop/contribute to it? Or you just want a binary version that you can run?

Comment: Just to learn it's internal works.

Comment: This isn't an error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're directly running the code from Intellij

You can ignore SLF4J warnings, but without a logging library enabled such as the default log4j you'll not see any console output.

This is why you'd run the provided `kafka-server-start` script rather than directly run the main method of the server class.

If you want to step through code in the IDE, you are able to use remote debugging to do that

If Gradle successfully builds the code, you're not getting any build errors

Comment: Yes, It isn't a bug. It works fine. Thank you. I can also debug it easily inside IntelliJ IDEA :)